# Unwanted output repetition and matrix search issues

Tags: c++

This code is an attempt to search for a target value (item) in a 5x5 matrix that I hard-coded values into. It queries the user for the value to be searched for. The problem is, when I run the code it tells me "Item found!" regardless of the user input. Also, It appears to be repeating user input. For example, when I used "87" as the user input, this is my output:

What is the value you'd like to search for? 878787Item found!

I'm fairly new to C++ so forgive me if I did something stupid. The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int target;
    int flag;
    int mat[5][5]= //hardcoded the matrix data
    {
       {1,2,3,4,5},
       {6,7,8,9,10},
       {11,12,13,14,15},
       {16,17,18,19,20},
       {21,22,23,24,25}
    };

    cout<<"What is the value you'd like to search for? ";
    cin>>target;

    for(int x=0;x<5;x++)
    {
        for(int y=0;y<5;y++)
        {
            if (mat[x][y]==target)
            {
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                //do nothing
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag == 1)
    {
        cout<<"Item found!";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Item not found.";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: all of you `<=`'s in your for loops need to be `<`'s.  Otherwise you have undefined behavior.

Comment: As Nathan pointed out you're making invalid accesses to your arrays. It may happen that the program is reading the `target` variable in one of those accesses and thus always "finds the item". By the way, your `break` statement only goes out of the inner loop, not the outer. So by setting `flag = 0` every iteration, even if you fix what Nathan pointed out, you'll still run into issues.

Comment: you can lose the else part as well no need of making flag to 0

Comment: OP I noticed you edited your code.  Does the updated version have the same issue?  I cannot replicate it in its current form.

Comment: I've made the changes that were recommended and tweaked a couple other things. Everything is working fine now. Thank you!

Comment: note: `break` only breaks the inner loop, not the outer loop! Also, your `else{//do nothing}` is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As aslg mentioned in his comment you break only your inner loop, you need to beak the outer `for(int x=0;x<5;x++)` loop as well. You can do this after the inner loop by stating:

```
if(flag==0){
   break;
}
```

But this is not a particularly elegant solution. I suggest you let the standard library do the job.

```
int* end = mat[0]+25;
int* found = std::find(mat[0],end,target);

if(found!=end)
{
    cout<<"Item found!";
}
else
{
    cout<<"Item not found.";
}
```

Whats going on here: In fact the static multidimensional 5x5 array is stored as a one-dimensional array of size 25. `mat[0]` points to its start and `mat[0] + 25` to its end. `std::find(start,end,target)` returns the pointer to the target if it can be found within [start,end[, else `end` is returned.